# L'énergie « sale » : simple antonyme de « propre » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, synonymes, origine-ou-raison, antonyme

> Je ne me sens pas du tout gêné de refuser de l'énergie sale, alors
>   que, nous, on offre de l'énergie propre à un prix très concurrentiel.
>
> [ Le premier ministre du Québec, M. François Legault, [cité](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/201812/11/01-5207685-petrole-sale-albertain-notley-repond-a-legault.php) par *La
>   presse* ; contexte de l'aria ([1](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/politique-quebecoise/201812/07/01-5207258-reunion-des-premiers-ministres-legault-dit-non-a-lenergie-sale.php),[2](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/politique-canadienne/201812/17/01-5208324-energie-sale-legault-se-defend-contre-les-attaques-de-lalberta.php)). ]

On qualifie ainsi dans la citation l'exploitation pétrolière qu'on oppose à l'hydro-électricité. On connaît les termes [*énergie propre*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2068475), [*non polluante*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=ENERGIE%20PROPRE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) et [*énergie verte*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26506769), *douce*, selon que l'énergie soit produite sans (ou avec très peu de) pollution et, de surcroît dans le cas de *verte*, avec des sources d'énergie [renouvelables](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8357810) en contexte de [développement durable](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2067322). L'exploitation du charbon, a déjà été [assimilée](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/201805/02/01-5169101-le-decret-sur-lenergie-sale.php) à de l'*énergie sale* dans les journaux...

- Le sens de l'expression « énergie sale » se constitue-t-il
  exclusivement par antonymie d(e)'« (énergie) propre » ; est-ce *polluant* et
  *non-renouvelable* à la fois : s'agit-il de synonymes ?
- Où et quand l'expression « énergie sale » est-elle attestée ou
  apparaît-elle pour le première fois ; pour le première fois pour décrire l'*exploitation pétrolière* ou les [énergies fossiles](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8423318) d'origine solaire ; est-ce avant ou après « énergie propre » etc. ?

Comment: Sur google scholar, la première occurence de *"énergie sale"* date de 1983. Elle semble effectivement s'opposer à *"énergie propre"*. [Recherche francophone exclusive](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=%22%C3%A9nergie+sale%22&hl=fr&lr=lang_fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=1500&as_yhi=2000)

Comment: @P.Manthe N'hésitez pas à verser votre trouvaille en réponse ! Merci !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Le sens de l'expression *énergie sale* se constitue-t-il exclusivement par antonymie d'*énergie propre* ?

Non. On peut entendre l'expression *énergie sale* toute seule. Cette expression est comprise par les francophones, mais il est à noter cependant que cette dernière est beaucoup moins utilisée qu'*energie propre* et *energie verte*.

Je ne suis pas sûr de l’étymologie d'*énergie sale* mais à mon avis cette expression a sans doute été en effet créée d'après l'expression *énergie propre*.

> *polluant* et *non-renouvelable*: s'agit-il de synonymes ?

Pas exactement. Une énergie polluante dégrade un écosystème par l'introduction de substances. Une énergie non-renouvelable n'est pas forcément polluante mais est basé sur la consommation de ressources qui se renouvellent moins vite que l'on en consomme:

- Le pétrole est **non-renouvelable et polluant**: au rythme actuel, le monde aura épuisé toutes les ressources de pétrole en 2050, c'est donc une énergie non-renouvelable. De plus, divers accidents comme celui de Deepwater Horizon ont déversé du pétrole dans des écosystèmes fragiles, détruisant la biodiversité locale: c'est donc une énergie polluante.
- Le solaire est **renouvelable mais polluant**: on n'arrivera jamais à court d'énergie solaire, mais la production de panneaux solaires utilise des métaux lourds non-recyclables
- L'éolien est **renouvelable et non-polluant**: on n'épuisera jamais le vent terrestre, et les éoliennes ont un faible impact sur l'écosystème.

A noter que dans l'absolu, aucune énergie ne peut être *complètement* non-polluante et renouvelable, il s'agit plus d’apposer ces adjectifs afin de les comparer les énergies les unes entre elles.

Comment: Merci, on apprécie la nuance dans l'application des concepts aux réalités !

Comment: Le pétrole pollue même la science... des études sont [_entachées de données incohérentes_](https://www.lapresse.ca/environnement/pollution/201902/18/01-5215174-sables-bitumineux-des-etudes-dimpact-entachees.php) et on peut voir de plus en plus un amalgame avec le [préjugé](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/national/201902/19/01-5215376-le-convoi-pour-les-oleoducs-converge-a-ottawa.php), sous le couvert du nationalisme, que ce soit par le truchement d'une attaque coordonnée contre les institutions internationales ou contre l'[UE](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/33895/3177).