# « Nouvelle fausse/fausse nouvelle» et «information fausse/fausse information» : utilité de l'ordre des mots ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, ordre-des-mots, formulation

En prenant connaissance du néologisme *infox*<sup>1</sup> de la [*Commission d'enrichissement de la langue française*](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000037460897) (France) je note aussi d'autres suggestions (et des nuances d'emploi au CELF) comme *information fallacieuse* ainsi que des séquences différentes pour les mêmes suggestions : *nouvelle fausse, fausse nouvelle, information fausse ou fausse information* (CELF).

---

- Peut-on expliquer l'utilité de l'ordre différents des mots dans les
  paires *nouvelle fausse/fausse nouvelle* et *information
  fausse/fausse information* à l'aide d'exemples au besoin ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26542775), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/infox) ; mot-valise formé de [*info*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/info), abréviation de *information*, et [*intox*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/intox), apocope d'[*intoxication*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intox) pour rendre l'expression anglo-saxonne [*fake news*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fake_news), à ne pas confondre avec la [nouvelle satirique](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26542779), soit « un ensemble de procédés contribuant à la désinformation du public » (CELF) ou la « publication qui imite la structure d'un article de presse, qui comprend à la fois des renseignements véridiques et des renseignements erronés » (GDT).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Oui, le sens des mots peut avoir une influence, mais ce n'est pas systématiquement le cas. Le plus souvent, les expressions diffèrent par un changement d'accent:

- **information fausse / nouvelle fausse**: accent sur le fait que c'est une information / une nouvelle
- **fausse information / fausse nouvelle**: accent sur le fait que l'information/la nouvelle est fausse (NB: plus idiomatique)

Exemple de cas où l'ordre des mots change le sens en profondeur:

- **faux vrai sac Chanel**: imitation d'un sac Chanel
- **vrai faux sac Chanel**: cette imitation n'essaie pas du tout de ressembler à un vrai sac Chanel et a tout ce qu'on pourrait attendre d'un *faux sac Chanel*, c'est donc un *vrai faux sac Chanel*

Ah, et en bonus:

- **Gorge rouge**: une gorge de couleur rouge
- **Rouge gorge**: espèce d'oiseau

Comment: Si vous avez l'occasion d'identifier des exemples réels avec ce qui apparaît dans le titre et où vous sentez ces nuances, puis de les ajouter à votre réponse, ce serait bien...

Comment: Un exemple tout frais [ici](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/201902/19/01-5215364-le-gouvernement-hongrois-denigre-le-president-de-la-commission-europeenne.php) : on a utilisé « fausses informations » mais entre guillemets... que de limitrophes indignes de Schengen, et antisémites en plus...